# Recorrer datos de un json con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Estoy intentando obtener la data de un json pero no al momento de buscar un dato me arroja el error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dia' of undefined

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  //dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  jsonpCallback: "myJSON",
  success: function (json) {
    alert(json);
    var subjson = json.substring(7, json.length-1);
    alert(subjson);
    var jsonValido = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + subjson + ")"));
    var jsonFinal = JSON.parse(JSONize(jsonValido));
    alert(jsonFinal);
    //$("#resultado").html(json);
    alert("obtencion de datos: Dia" + jsonFinal[0]['dia'] + " A: " + jsonFinal[0]['A']);
    $("#resultado").html(jsonFinal[0]);
  }
```

He revisado como obtener datos y vi que esa es la forma `jsonFinal[0]['dia']`, pero no he logrado acceder a ellos.

el json al que estoy consultando los datos tiene este formato

```
{'dia':'01-08-2016','A':'3','B':'5','C':'33','D':'34','E':'3'},{'dia':'02-08-2016','A':'3','B':'3','C':'38','D':'30','E':'3'}
```

Comment: `alert(jsonFinal);` te imprime exactamente el json que muestras?

Comment: imprime [object Object]

Comment: Reemplaza `alert(jsonFinal)` por `console.log(jsonFinal)`, abre la consola para desarrolladores y publica lo que te imprime.

Comment: Ese JSON debería de tener corchetes, se te olvidó ponerlos o no los tiene ?

Comment: cuando dices tener los corchetes debería esta así? `{{'dia':'01-08-2016','A':'3','B':'5','C':'33','D':'34','E':'3'},{'dia':'02-08-2016','A':'3','B':'3','C':'38','D':'30','E':'3'}}` ??

Comment: Stevn, asi: `[{'dia':'01-08-2016','A':'3','B':'5','C':'33','D':'34','E':'‌​3'},{'dia':'02-08-20‌​16','A':'3','B':'3',‌​'C':'38','D':'30','E‌​':'3'}]`

Comment: Comprendo, así es como lo imprime en la consola `{dia: "21-02-2015", A: "4", B: "3", C: "41", D: "33"}`

Comment: Esta mal formado tu JSON, si esperas un arreglo de objetos tiene que que llevar corechetes como te lo puso @Einer

Comment: Stevn, lo que estas imprimiendo en consola **no** se trata de un JSON sino de una **variable JavaScript**. Es más el hecho de ver comentado el `dataType` demuestra que no es JSON. Se trata de `JSONP` en realidad es decir `JavaScript`

Comment: Faltaba la forma que Einer y Lato mencionaron, faltaban los corchetes. Ahora puedo acceder a los datos de forma correcta. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El formato que pones es incorrecto

```
{'dia':'01-08-2016','A':'3','B':'5','C':'33','D':'34','E':'3'},{'dia':'02-08-2016','A':'3','B':'3','C':'38','D':'30','E':'3'}
```

Para que sea un arreglo de objetos tiene que estar encerrado entre corchetes

```
[{'dia':'01-08-2016','A':'3','B':'5','C':'33','D':'34','E':'3'},{'dia':'02-08-2016','A':'3','B':'3','C':'38','D':'30','E':'3'}]
```

Los objetos en JSON se encierran entre llaves **{ }**  y dentro de las llaves van las propiedades de los objetos con sus respectivos valores (entre comillas) separados por **:** (dos puntos)

```
{ propiedad:"valor" }
```

Varias propiedades se separan por comas

```
{ propiedad:"valor", otro:"su valor" }
```

Para poder agrupar varios objetos se tienen que poner entre corchetes (como un arreglo) y separar cada objeto con una coma

```
[ {propiedad:"valor"} , {otra:"valor"} ]
```

Un buen tutorial corto [aqui](https://geekytheory.com/json-i-que-es-y-para-que-sirve-json/)

Comment: Podrías complementar un poco más la respuesta para poder elegirla. Por si alguien mas entra. Gracias.

Comment: Listo, la complemente y agregue una liga a un pequeño tutorial en español

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza `jsonFinal[0]['dia']` cuando tengas un arreglo de objetos.

Por la información que has puesto dentro de los comentarios, tú tienes un solo objeto no un arreglo, así que la forma para acceder a la propiedad debería ser:

```
jsonFinal['dia']
```

ó

```
jsonFinal.dia
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un arreglo de esta manera:

```
[{'dia':'01-08-2016','A':'3','B':'5','C':'33','D':'34','E':'3'},{'dia':'02-08-2016','A':'3','B':'3','C':'38','D':'30','E':'3'}]
```

Puedes acceder al elemento que querias de esta manera

```
//jsonFinal es el objeto devuelto por la solicitud del ajax que anteriormente mencionabas
var dia = jsonFinal[0].dia;
```

Si quieres acceder a cualquier otra propiedad solo tienes que llamarla despues del punto
     var A = jsonFinal[0].A;   //o .B o cualquiera que tenga